# vb.net Backgroundwork UI is not updating

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm new to background worker. Can anyone check what's wrong with my code?, Please. My problem is calling reportprogress from another function don't change anything on my UI.

Given: PopulateFolders is my backgroundworker.

From this code is from another class and it calls setStatus from main form.

```
Public Sub populate(Optional ByVal iFilePath As String = "")
    'Dim strFilePaths() As String
    'strFilePaths = IO.Directory.GetFiles(_Path)
    Dim FileName() As String
    If iFilePath = "" Then iFilePath = _Path
    Dim counter As Integer = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(iFilePath)).Count
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    For Each file__1 As String In Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(iFilePath))
        frmMain.lblProgess.Text = "Getting info of:" & file__1
        FileContent.Add(file__1)
        FileName = Split(file__1, "\")
        FileName(0) = IIf(FileName(UBound(FileName)) <> "", FileName(UBound(FileName)), FileName(UBound(FileName) - 1))
        i = i + 1
        If i Mod 25 = 0 Then frmMain.SetStatus(FileName(0), (i / counter) * 100)
    Next

    For Each folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Path.GetDirectoryName(iFilePath))
        If folder(folder.Length - 1) <> "\" Then folder = folder & "\"
        populate(folder)
    Next
End Sub
```

This is the code from my main class. From PopulateFCollections I can just update my UI without any problem.

———————————————————————————————————

```
Public Structure ControlWithText
    Public ControlName As Control
    Public Text As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal text As String)
        Me.ControlName = ctrl
        Me.Text = text
    End Sub
End Structure

Private Sub PopulateFolders_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles PopulateFolders.DoWork

    PopulateFCollections(folderTo)

End Sub

Private Sub PopulateFCollections(ByVal item As List(Of clsFolder))
    Dim msg As String = ""
    Dim iFldr As New List(Of clsFolder)
    Dim iFldrTemp As New clsFolder
    Dim i As Integer = 1

    PopulateFolders.ReportProgress(0)
    For Each iFolder As clsFolder In item
        PopulateFolders.ReportProgress(CInt((i / item.Count) * 100), New ControlWithText(lblProgess, "Extracting FIles from:..." & iFolder.FolderName))
        msg = msg & iFolder.FolderName & "; " & iFolder.FilePath & ";" & _
            iFolder.Username & "; " & iFolder.Password & vbCrLf
        iFldrTemp = iFolder
        iFldrTemp.populate()
        iFldr.Add(iFldrTemp)
        i = +1
    Next
    MsgBox(msg)
End Sub

Public Sub SetStatus(ByVal txt As String, ByVal percentage As Integer)
        PopulateFolders.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        PopulateFolders.ReportProgress(percentage, New ControlWithText(lblProgess, "Adding.. " & txt & ".."))
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: How are you defining frmMain in your other class, you show it being used but not declared. Make sure you are not newing up another instance of the form, which would give the symptoms you describe.

Comment: @MarkHall I just found out how to do it. I really don't know how it calls. I put my UI objects and background worker into new declared objects like `Dim objBGW as system.componentModel.Backgroundworker` then set it to `objBGW = myBGW` and it works. I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer to my problem but if you have better solution. I'm open enough to accept corrections so I can do, know, and understand better.

Here's my solution I don't really understand though but enough for me to accomplish a part of my work.

I just make a new variable instance to handle my objects.

```
Public Shared bgw As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
Public Shared lblCurProgess As Label
```

from Private Sub PopulateFCollections i set bgw and label

```
Private Sub PopulateFCollections(ByVal item As List(Of clsFolder))


bgw = PopulateFolders
lblCurProgess = lblProgess


Dim msg As String = ""
Dim iFldr As New List(Of clsFolder)
Dim iFldrTemp As New clsFolder
Dim i As Integer = 1

PopulateFolders.ReportProgress(0)
For Each iFolder As clsFolder In item
    PopulateFolders.ReportProgress(CInt((i / item.Count) * 100), New ControlWithText(lblProgess, "Extracting FIles from:..." & iFolder.FolderName))
    msg = msg & iFolder.FolderName & "; " & iFolder.FilePath & ";" & _
        iFolder.Username & "; " & iFolder.Password & vbCrLf
    iFldrTemp = iFolder
    iFldrTemp.populate()
    iFldr.Add(iFldrTemp)
    i = +1
Next
MsgBox(msg)
End Sub
```

And this how I call it from another class/function

```
If i Mod 25 = 0 Then frmMain.bgw.ReportProgress((i / counter) * 100, New frmMain.ControlWithText(frmMain.lblCurProgess, "Getting info... " & FileName(0) & ".."))
```

and it just works. I can now see my ui moving :D

If you have a better solution to this, please post you answer. I will greatly appreciate someone correcting me to be able do better and learn.

Thanks,